# Loop over fields in a dynamic WTForm

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am a rookie in Flask, and try to create dynamic input fields. I came across a solution where I can create the template in Flask and then I have to iterate in my .html file with the following code:

```
{% from 'your_form_template.jinja' import forms %}
    {% for address_entry_form in form.addresses %}
    {{ address_entry_form.hidden_tag() }}
    {# Flask-WTF needs `hidden_tag()` so CSRF works for each form #}
    {{ forms.render_field(address_entry_form.name) }}
    {% endfor %}
```

I can't figure out what do I need to put in the first line instead of 'your_form_template.jinja'

I only have a simple app structure:

app
|
Templates--
|         |
|         Index.html
app.py

Answer (score 1):

Your top line wouldn't be in your html, you'd pass the variable `addresses` to jinja.  So in `app.py` import your `forms` module and:

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET','POST'))
def index():
#stuff you're doing in index
return render_template('index.html', adresses=forms.addresses) #assuming forms.addresses here is actually a list of forms
```

Then the html would have

```
{% for address_entry_form in adresses %}
....
```